# Adding a CellImage from One Google Sheet to Another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to a previous question, I have been trying to add a CellImage created with a formula in one Google Sheet and putting it into another Google Sheet.

I have a CellImage created in the first sheet with the formula:

```
=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&B1)
```

The following is an Apps Script I made that should take the CellImage from the first sheet and insert it into a cell on the second sheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.create("QR Holder");
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  let sheet2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  sheet2.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue());
}
```

The execution log says that for the last line:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
```

This shows that the getValue() used on the image in Sheet 1 is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')`, in this case, it is considered that your sheet names of `Sheet 1` or `Sheet 2` might not be existing. So, please confirm your sheet names again.

And, if a formula of `=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&B1)` is put in a cell "A1" of "Sheet 1" sheet using the valid sheet names, and when you want to copy the cell value to the cell "A1" of "Sheet 2", unfortunately, I'm worried that an error like `Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets` might occur at `sheet2.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue());`.

So, in this answer, in order to copy the cell value, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modified script:

**Before you use this script, please confirm your sheet names again.**

```js
function myFunction() {
  // let doc = DocumentApp.create("QR Holder"); // In your script, it seems that this is not used.
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  let sheet2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  sheet1.getRange(1, 1).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

- If you want to copy the formula, please modify `sheet1.getRange(1, 1).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });` to `sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,2).copyTo(sheet2.getRange(1,1));`. By this, the formula and the value of "B1" are copied.

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Answer (score 0):

This runs for me:

```
function myFunction() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sheet2.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheet1.getRange(1,1).getValue());
  Logger.log(sheet2.getRange("A1").getValue());
}
```